# lazy loading table with emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi is there a way in Ember to lazy load stuff into a table? I am loading the first page initially but then as the user scrolls down I want to load ping the second page API call and add that into the table. Is there a way of doing that in Ember? A link to a tutorial will be highly appreciated. I cannot seem to find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ember-Table](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/overview) is a pre-built component that does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks GJK. but where do I add the logic for pinging the URLs here? I cannot find that in the [API doc](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/documentation)

Comment: There's a small example [here](http://addepar.github.io/#/ember-table/ajax) that shows you something like that. I have to say though, you should already be familiar with Ember.js and lazy loading data before you tackle a problem like this.

Comment: GJK, by lazy loading data you mean using jQuery Promises right?

Comment: By lazy loading, I mean fetching the data via AJAX requests when it's needed and not before. You can accomplish that multiple ways. jQuery Promises is one way to do that, but since you're working with Ember, Ember-Data (or one of it's alternatives) would probably integrate nicer.